# Is it possible to create GridView in Alertdialog?

Tags: java, android, gridview

Is it possible to create a GridView within an alert dialogue?

At the moment i have a word search, and I want to display the solution ( completed word search) in a pop up dialog, so the user can quickly switch bertween their puzzle, and the answers.

I've tried implementing it like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 // set title
 aBuilder.setTitle("The solution");
    GridView g = null ;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> Wordadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.wordsstyle, WordsToFind);
    g.setNumColumns(Length);
    g.setAdapter(Wordadapter);
     aBuilder.setView(g);
 aBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
 {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
 {
 }
});
```

However it just crashes

im getting this in my log cat though

```
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  ... 11 more
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.example.angrywordsearch.Puzzle_Activity.GridPopup(Puzzle_Activity.java:726)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.example.angrywordsearch.Puzzle_Activity.ViewSolution_Click(Puzzle_Activity.java:686)
04-24 21:17:48.472: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `g.setNumColumns(Length)`, but `g` is `null` at that moment. Therefore the `NullPointerException` in your LogCat. You need to initialize the `GridView` somehow, possibly by `GridView g = new GridView(this);`.

Answer (score 1):

You could start an ActivityForResult that uses the DialogTheme to show itself as a Dialog.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Example: 
`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">`

From there, you could return the selected result from the grid with Activity's setResult(int) method.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this and have better control over the actual layout is by creating a dialog and inflating a custom XML containing a gridview.
The xml itself is simply an xml like any other layout, the only difference is when we inflate it, it will only fill our dialog and not our whole screen like a normal root layout.
So first we create the dialog:

```
//create the dialog
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());

//remove the default title if you want to
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//here is where we inflate our custom xml containing a gridview
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.grid_dialog);
```

Now we have our dialog object with a reference to our custom xml, lets say in that XML we have a gridview named 'my_grid' we can now reference it via our dialog object like this:

```
Gridview myGrid = (Gridview) dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_grid);
```

Now that you have a reference to your gridview you can do anything you normally would do with a gridview such a setting a custom adapter.

For any other layout object you want to reference such as a textview or a button simply go about it the same way.

If you want to set the exact size of your dialog, just set the width and height of your most outer parent and the dialog will expand to that size.

Answer (score 0):

Necessarily have to be a gridview?... Cause you cand add an items array  into a alertdialog, something like a listview... Check this out:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
     // Do something with the selection
}
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: The gridview is to make a wordsearch, as that is how i've done it in my actual game, making the solution a different way seems a bit superfluous

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is Just do Any kind of Gridview design in your activity. If you want to show that activity as the dialog in means just set the theme of that activity in Android manifest file as `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` as usual use the startActivity to invoke your grid view. Then it will open as the Dialog form.(May be it will look like custom dialog ) . at the same time before setcontent view use (Window.nofeatureDialog) .to avoid the title for the dialog.

Hope this will help you.